# why wont my background change color?

Tags: java, swing

I was working on this lab in class and when I tried changing the background color it would stay at its default of white can someone please explain where I my programming went wrong.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class  DemoPoly extends JFrame {  

// constructor
public DemoPoly() {
  // defines Frame characteristics

  int size = 300;
  setSize(size,size);
  setTitle("a random window");

  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);

  setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setVisible(true);
}

public static void main (String[] args){ 
  //  instantiates a JFrame
  //  exits on close (opional)
  JFrame object = new DemoPoly();
} 

public void  paint  (Graphics g){
  // This provides the Graphics object g,  where
  // you are going to use you graphics primitive
  // to paint on the content pane of the frame.
  int[] arr = {0,100,100,0};
  int[] yarr = {0,0,100,100};
  Square object = new Square(arr,yarr,Color.red);
  AbstractPolygon randSquare = new Square(arr, yarr, Color.red);
}
```

Comment: An explanation of Java graphics or screen objects is too broad for this site.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of problems in your code:

1. Extending `JFrame` is like saying your class **is a** `JFrame`, `JFrame` is a rigid container, instead create your GUI based on `JPanel`s. See [Java Swing extends JFrame vs calling it inside of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41252329/java-swing-using-extends-jframe-vs-calling-it-inside-of-class) for more information.
2. You're breaking the paint chain by removing the `super.paint(g)` call on the `paint(...)` method. When changing your GUI to extend `JPanel` instead of `JFrame` you should use the `paintComponent(...)` method instead. Take the [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).
3. You forgot to add `@Override` notation on the `paint(...)` method.
4. You're not placing your program on the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) which could cause threading issues.

   You can solve this by changing your `main()` method like this:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               //Your constructor here
           }
       });
   }
   ```
5. Instead of setting the `JFrame` size, override the `getPreferredSize()` method and call `pack()`. See [Should I setPreferred|Maximum|MiniumSize in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi). The general consensus says yes.

---

Your problem gets solved by adding

```
super.paint(g);
```

on the `paint(...)` method:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g); //Never remove this
    //Your code goes here
}
```

---

With all the above recommendations taken into account, your code should look like this now:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class DemoPoly {

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DemoPoly().createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

    public void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());

        CustomPanel cp = new CustomPanel();
        cp.setBackground(Color.RED);
        frame.add(cp);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

class CustomPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }
}
```

Which produces this output (and is the same output that you'll get with your current code but better because it gives you more control over your components)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't understand your question. But here is code for change your background to RED;

```
public class DemoPoly extends JFrame {

    public DemoPoly() {
        // defines Frame characteristics

        int size = 300;
        setSize(size, size);
        setTitle("a random window");

        //change background here
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //  instantiates a JFrame
        //  exits on close (opional)
        JFrame object = new DemoPoly();
    }
}
```

Your code is well. Maybe use @override in your paint method.